# Need Help: MongoDB Startup Failure - Seeking Solutions and Advice

Tags: mongodb

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

Job for `mongod.service` failed because the control process exited with error code.

> See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
>
> systemctl status mongod.service
> ● mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-08-24 12:10:28 IST; 14s ago
> Process: 846282 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/percona-server-mongodb-helper.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
> Process: 846318 ExecStart=/usr/bin/env bash -c ${NUMACTL} /usr/bin/mongod ${OPTIONS} > ${STDOUT} 2> ${STDERR} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> Aug 24 12:10:28 rbtQKfk systemd[1]: Starting High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database...
> Aug 24 12:10:28 rbtQKfk percona-server-mongodb-helper.sh[846303]: touch: cannot touch '/var/log/mongodb/mongod.stdout': No such file or directory
> Aug 24 12:10:28 rbtQKfk percona-server-mongodb-helper.sh[846303]: touch: cannot touch '/var/log/mongodb/mongod.stderr': No such file or directory
> Aug 24 12:10:28 rbtQKfk percona-server-mongodb-helper.sh[846305]: chown: cannot access '/var/log/mongodb': No such file or directory
> Aug 24 12:10:28 rbtQKfk env[846319]: bash: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.stdout: No such file or directory
> Aug 24 12:10:28 rbtQKfk systemd[1]: mongod.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
> Aug 24 12:10:28 rbtQKfk systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
> Aug 24 12:10:28 rbtQKfk systemd[1]: Failed to start High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.

`journalctl -xe`

> Aug 24 12:42:38 rbtQKfk multipathd[739]: sda: add missing path
> Aug 24 12:42:38 rbtQKfk multipathd[739]: sda: failed to get udev uid: Invalid argument
> Aug 24 12:42:38 rbtQKfk multipathd[739]: sda: failed to get sysfs uid: Invalid argument
> Aug 24 12:42:38 rbtQKfk multipathd[739]: sda: failed to get sgio uid: No such file or directory

`logfile`

> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-24T12:11:55.749+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-24T12:11:55.759+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-24T12:11:55.759+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20254,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Read security file failed","attr":{"error":{"code":30,"codeName":"InvalidPath","errmsg":"error opening file: /var/lib/mongodb-pki/keyfile: bad file"}}}
> ~

Comment: Error message `"error opening file: /var/lib/mongodb-pki/keyfile: bad file"` should be quite clear. Check the file. Maybe it does not exist or the mongod user lacks read privileges. Also error `cannot access '/var/log/mongodb': No such file or directory` seems to be obvious.